# Global Variables declaration, compare and assign in Drools Decision

Tags: drools

I have a scenario where I need to use global Boolean variable which needs to set to true when one of the rule executes and that global will be used in other rules as condition. I took the example with simple decision table, attached the same for your reference. [decision table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH4RL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. It does not work, by definition.

Use a fact to record results that should influence left hand side logic.